# Material UI v5 cardMedia images not showing in deployed site

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, netlify

I am mapping an array of objects to display a set of MUI cards with the "cardMedia" component. The images show well in my localhost but when I deployed to netlify, the images were broken.

This is the mapped code

```
{
          AboutUs.map(info=>(
            <Card key={info.id} className='shadow-none bg-transparent'>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                image={info.imgUrl}
                className='w-16 h-auto ml-3'
              />
              <CardContent>
              <p className='text-2xl font-bold mr-2 my-3.5'>{info.title}</p>
              <p className='text-base'>{info.information}</p> 
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          ))
        }
```

Below is the exported Data;

```
export const AboutUs = [
  {
    id:1, 
    title:"Property Insurance",
    information:"We offer our customer property protection of liability coverage and insurance for their better life.",
    imgUrl:"./src/assets/icons-large/property_insurance.svg"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

as you addressed the `imgUrl` in your localhost directory, you've to require the image in order to be bundled with your app so it can be displayed in your VPS.

```
<CardMedia
  component="img"
  image={require(info.imgUrl)}
  className='w-16 h-auto ml-3'
 />
```

Comment: I tried this out and I kept getting a "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this issue was because I was using React Vite, I solved the issue by placing my entire assets folder in my public folder and since it was a root path I called it from the array like this;

```
export const AboutUs = [
  {
    id:1, 
    title:"Property Insurance",
    information:"We offer our customer property protection of liability coverage and insurance for their better life.",
    imgUrl:"/assets/icons-large/property_insurance.svg"
  },
]
```

Now the page renders without issues in Netlify